# Vectorizing a code that requires to complement some elements of a binary array

Tags: arrays, matlab, performance, matrix, vectorization

I have a matrix `A` of dimension `m`-by-`n` composed of zeros and ones, and a matrix `J` of dimension `m`-by-1 reporting some integers from `[1,...,n]`.

I want to construct a matrix `B` of dimension `m`-by-`n` such that for `i = 1,...,m`

1. `B(i,j) = A(i,j)` for `j=1,...,n-1`
2. `B(i,n) = abs(A(i,n)-1)`
3. If `sum(B(i,:))` is **odd** then `B(i,J(i)) = abs(B(i,J(i))-1)`

This code does what I want:

```
m = 4;
n = 5;
A = [1 1 1 1 1; ...
   0 0 1 0 0; ...
   1 0 1 0 1; ...
   0 1 0 0 1];
J = [1;2;1;4];
B = zeros(m,n);
for i = 1:m
    B(i,n) = abs(A(i,n)-1);
    for j = 1:n-1
        B(i,j) = A(i,j);
    end
    if mod(sum(B(i,:)),2)~=0
       B(i,J(i)) = abs(B(i,J(i))-1);
    end
 end
```

Can you suggest more efficient algorithms, that do not use the nested loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No for loops are required for your question. It just needs an effective use of the `colon` operator and logical-indexing as follows:

```
% First initialize B to all zeros
B = zeros(size(A));
% Assign all but last columns of A to B
B(:, 1:end-1) = A(:, 1:end-1);
% Assign the last column of B based on the last column of A
B(:, end) = abs(A(:, end) - 1);
% Set all cells to required value
% Original code which does not work: B(oddRow, J(oddRow)) = abs(B(oddRow, J(oddRow)) - 1);
% Correct code:
% Find all rows in B with an odd sum
oddRow = find(mod(sum(B, 2), 2) ~= 0);
for ii = 1:numel(oddRow)
    B(oddRow(ii), J(oddRow(ii))) = abs(B(oddRow(ii), J(oddRow(ii))) - 1);
end
```

I guess for the last part it is best to use a `for` loop.

Edit: See the neat trick by [EBH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44954385/7878502) to do the last part without a `for` loop

Comment: I saw your post and then saw it was deleted. You were just a wee bit late

Comment: Well, I was answering from my phone, so it took some extra time for typing ;)

Comment: well there are only some questions that have such a perfect solution

Comment: @ammportal Sorry, could you clarify the last step? I am running your code with other examples and it does not work. Try with `A= [1 1 0 1 0; 0 0 0 1 1; 0 0 1 1 1; 1 0 1 0 0]` and `J=[3;4;4;2]`

Comment: @ Sorry, there was a mistake. I have made the relevant changes

Comment: @user3285148 See my answer for doing the last part without a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to [@ammportal good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44954364/2627163), also the last part can be done without a loop with the use of [linear indices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511). For that, [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html?s_tid=doc_ta) is useful. So adopting the last part of the previous answer, this can be done:

```
% Find all rows in B with an odd sum
oddRow = find(mod(sum(B, 2), 2) ~= 0);
% convert the locations to linear indices
ind = sub2ind(size(B),oddRow,J(oddRow));
B(ind) = abs(B(ind)- 1);
```

Comment: included a link to your answer in mine